# Telegram.Bot not working SendDocumentAsync()

Tags: c#, file, telegram-bot

I use version of Telegram.Bot nuget package as 19.0.0

For some reason don't work method witch sent documents in chat.

```
public async ValueTask<(bool isOk, UploadedFilePayload payload)> UploadFileAsync(string name, Stream browserFileStream)
    {
        try
        {
            var inFile  = InputFile.FromStream(browserFileStream, name);
            var message = await TgBotClient.SendDocumentAsync(
                  chatId: _botsContext.FilesStore,
                 caption: $"File: {name}",
                document: inFile);

            return (true, new UploadedFilePayload { document = message.Document });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"File upload failed: {name}\n{ex.Message}");
            
            return (false, new UploadedFilePayload { Error = ex.Message });
        }
        finally
        {
            browserFileStream.Close();
            browserFileStream.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

While debugging, I see how the worker thread enters this method and stops in method `SendDocumentAsync()` without any errors. Maybe someone have some problem?